# Variable boolean doesnt work in a @Input and *ngif

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

sorry for my bad english, not my main language.

I got a problem, i have a boolean var in a father component to switch language. I have 2 ngifs in all my component to switch language if var is true or false.

app component:

```
  public euskera: boolean;


  constructor(){
    this.euskera=false;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  setEuskera(){
    this.euskera=true;
  }

  setCastellano(){
    this.euskera=false;
  }
```

app component html:

```
<div *ngIf="euskera">
  <header id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="../assets/img/logoSoinuka.png">
      <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
  
          <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']"><a>hasiera</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/sobre-nosotros']"><a>nor gara?</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/proximos-eventos']"><a>hurrengo ekitaldiak</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/contacto']"><a>kontaktua</a></li>
          <li (mouseenter)="mostrarLenguajes()" (mouseleave)="esconderLenguajes()"><a>Hizkuntza:<span>[</span></a></li>
        </ul>
  
      </nav>
  
  
  </header>

  <div id="language" (mouseenter)="mostrarLenguajes()" (mouseleave)="esconderLenguajes()">
    <ul>
  
      <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']" (click)="setCastellano()"><a>Gaztelania</a></li>
      <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']" (click)="setEuskera()"><a>Euskara</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="son">
    <app-home [euskera]="true"></app-home>
  </div>
  
</div>


<div *ngIf="euskera==false">
  <header id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="../assets/img/logoSoinuka.png">
      <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
  
          <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']"><a>Inicio</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/sobre-nosotros']"><a>¿Quienes somos?</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/proximos-eventos']"><a>Proximos eventos</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/contacto']"><a>Contacto</a></li>
          <li (mouseenter)="mostrarLenguajes()" (mouseleave)="esconderLenguajes()"><a>Lenguaje:<span>[</span></a></li>
        </ul>
  
      </nav>
  
  
  </header>

  <div id="language" (mouseenter)="mostrarLenguajes()" (mouseleave)="esconderLenguajes()">
    <ul>
  
      <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']" (click)="setCastellano()"><a>Castellano</a></li>
      <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']" (click)="setEuskera()"><a>Euskera</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="son">
    <app-home [euskera]="false"></app-home>
  </div>
</div>




<body>
  <div id="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  </div>
</body>
```

So far everything works. The problem is, when I pass the variable to the child and do the input.

Home component (child)

```
public title: string
  @Input() euskera:boolean;
```

Home component html (child)

```
<div *ngIf="euskera">
  euskk
</div>

<div *ngIf="euskera==false">
dd
</div>
```

At this point the Ifs stop working. It does neither of the two checks for me, neither false nor true.

When I reload the page, as soon as I start, when outputting the input value from the child through the console it gives me false (its real value) but then without doing anything it marks undefined.

Then it no longer matters if I press the button to change language and change the value of the variable since it does not modify the text of the child.

Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: Try `*ngIf="!euskera"` since it's `undefined` not `false`.

Comment: @JaromandaX Its angular, sorry

Comment: @elclanrs Thank you. That has worked for me for part of the conditional. How can I do when it is true?

Comment: @Adromicfms Try `*ngIf="euskera"` or `*ngIf="euskera === true"`

Comment: I tried but my input always return an undefined. When i change the value manually pressing button doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

use !euskera to check if a value is null or undefined or false

```
<div *ngIf="euskera">
  euskara
</div>

<div *ngIf="!euskera">
 castellano
</div>
```

You can also give a value by defect in input

```
@Input() euskera:boolean=false
```

Comment: I just did it and the false part works. But when I press the menu button to change to true the text of the content is not modified while the value of the variable collected in the console appears to me as true.